# QGIS delimited text import CRS not being defined

Tags: qgis, csv

I've recently updated to both the long term release and 2.10 versions of QGIS and the delimited text plugin has stopped working.

Everytime I try to add a CSV file and say ok on the plugin it no longer asks for me to define the CRS and then defaults to WGS 84 (image below). Given I work in UTM it's a massive hassle to convert to long/lat everytime just so it wil display correctly so i can transform it to UTM.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please make sure that you have set **Prompt for CRS** under *Settings / Options / CRS*. Or you can set any CRS as default there to your liking.

[image: CRS settings for new and loaded layers]